# Commit Transaction with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I downloaded a Spring Data JPA example from here [Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) and it works as expected.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
  }

  @Bean
  public CommandLineRunner demo(CustomerRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {
      // save a couple of customers
      repository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"));
      repository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian"));
      repository.save(new Customer("Kim", "Bauer"));
      repository.save(new Customer("David", "Palmer"));
      repository.save(new Customer("Michelle", "Dessler"));

      // fetch all customers
      log.info("Customers found with findAll():");
      log.info("-------------------------------");
      for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
        log.info(customer.toString());
      }
      log.info("");

      // fetch an individual customer by ID
      Customer customer = repository.findOne(1L);
      log.info("Customer found with findOne(1L):");
      log.info("--------------------------------");
      log.info(customer.toString());
      log.info("");

      // fetch customers by last name
      log.info("Customer found with findByLastName('Bauer'):");
      log.info("--------------------------------------------");
      for (Customer bauer : repository.findByLastName("Bauer")) {
        log.info(bauer.toString());
      }
      log.info("");
    };
  }

}
```

Then I tried to change from In-Memory database to a real one. For this I added in the current directory an `application.properties` file with a single line:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:C:/users/semaphor/H2Database;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Now when I run the application, I can see that in the expected directory the database file is created.

Now I want to see that the customers are stored in the database and are still there when I restart the application. So I removed some lines where customers were saved in the database at the beginning but they are then not listen with `findAll()`.

I suppose this transaction is not commited but I can't figure out how I can do this. Adding simply the annotation `@EnableTranscationManagement` to the Application class and `@Transactional` to the `demo()` method is not the solution.

What do I have to add to commit the transaction (if that is really the problem)?

Comment: check the creation time of the DB file, maybe it's recreate at startup.

Comment: This '@Transactional' might be ignored when placed there. Can you try externalizing the calls to your repository into a method in another class, and annotate '@Transactional' this method?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-creating-and-dropping-jpa-databases
Check your data with the H2 web console

Comment: Following KayKay suggestion you may want to create an external service annotated with '@Service' and '@Transactional' where you inject an '@Autowired' repository. As far as I remember '@Bean' annotation does not have any transactional capability.

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque I checked it, the file is not recreated.

Comment: @KayKay I'm unsure how to move it in an external class. How is then the method invoked?

Comment: @medveshonok117 I'm a beginner with spring, so I have no idea how to use '@Service', I will try to google that.

Comment: Although the file isn't recreated the schema is, as H2 is considered an embedded DB, at startup the existing schema is dropped and recreated. Hence your data is gone. Set the creation for the schema explicitly to update. The problem is not related to the working of the transaction but with the recreation of the schema.

Comment: @M.Deinum I added 'spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update' to the application.properties file and that was the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See M. Deinum's comment below the question.

Adding

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

to the `application.properties` was the solution.